# What's the equivalent of GitLab's `artifacts:reports:dotenv` keyword in GitHub Actions?

Tags: github, gitlab, github-actions

What's the equivalent of GitLab's `artifacts:reports:dotenv` keyword in GitHub Actions?

I use the `artifacts:reports:dotenv` keyword to set environment variables to be used by successive jobs in GitLab CI:

```
artifacts:
  reports:
    dotenv: aws.env
  expire_in: 2 hours
```

How can I achieve the same in GitHub Actions?

Comment: If you mean how do you export artifacts, see https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts. Or maybe you want a workflow with outputs: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#using-outputs-from-a-reusable-workflow. There's no reason to expect an exact equivalent, think about what you're trying to _do_ with it.

Comment: Thank you. But then I need to `export` the values into the environment myself, right? GitLab does that for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use can [`GITHUB_STATE`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#sending-values-to-the-pre-and-post-actions) or [`GITHUB_ENV`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable).

From the docs:

> This example uses JavaScript to write to the GITHUB_STATE file. The resulting environment variable is named STATE_processID with the value of 12345:

```js
import * as fs from 'fs'
import * as os from 'os'

fs.appendFileSync(process.env.GITHUB_STATE, `processID=12345${os.EOL}`, {
  encoding: 'utf8'
})
```

Or setting an env variable using bash and `GITHUB_ENV`:

```bash
echo "{environment_variable_name}={value}" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
```

> You can make an environment variable available to any subsequent steps in a workflow job by defining or updating the environment variable and writing this to the `GITHUB_ENV` environment file. The step that creates or updates the environment variable does not have access to the new value, but all subsequent steps in a job will have access.

For example:

```yaml
steps:
  - name: Set the value
    id: step_one
    run: |
      echo "action_state=yellow" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
  - name: Use the value
    id: step_two
    run: |
      printf '%s\n' "$action_state" # This will output 'yellow'
```

This would be roughly equivalent to GitLab's dotenv report like so:

```yaml
job_one:
  script:
    - echo "action_state=yellow" >> my.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: my.env
job_two
  needs: [job_one]
  script:
    - echo "${action_state}"  # 'yellow'
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's only shared between steps, not individual jobs, like it's the case with GitLab?

Comment: @Shuzheng right, it's local to those steps. If you want to pass data between _jobs_, see [passing data between jobs in a workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts#passing-data-between-jobs-in-a-workflow) -- for passing secrets between jobs or workflows, see [this example](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#example-masking-and-passing-a-secret-between-jobs-or-workflows)